# Mysql, group_concat performance: split huge table

Tags: mysql, performance, group-concat

I've a huge table **231,451,584 rows, 14 columns, 15.1 GiB size**.

The last 3 columns have data that will be `group_concat` into 3 different tables (resuming the number of rows to ≈2,500 by eliminate the redundancy of the first 11 columns and merging the values of columns #12 or #13 or #14 into a big comma separated, csv formatted text).

This operation (the group_concat insert on each new table) takes a **huge time** (`≈18.000 seconds` per new table).

It should be fast if I **split my first table into 3** (same 11 columns first, and just a last one with the different values I want to concat, for each new table)?

I'm asking this here because it takes to long to get a benchmark for my case.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want the [second normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).  Perhaps you would do well to add an integer `id` column to act as the PK in your existing table (use MySQL's [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) feature to automatically assign values if you wish): then you could use such key as FK in the new table.  I'd avoid performing `GROUP_CONCAT()` to inserting CSV (which is a violation of the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)) unless you have very good reason.

Comment: I've already an increment id. The reason I'm doing this is I'm using RapidMiner to classifying and process some clustering analysis and it inner structure is CSV based. The performance goes way down if I create this CSV in this java-based application instead of directly store the data into a huge, already formatted, string.

Comment: Okay, provided you don't need to query the data in any other way, that sounds like a reasonable case for denormalisation.

Comment: You are right, but this table is already a concatenation of multiple, key oriented, tables. Why is that? because the group_concat made from multiple table crosses (and so on) was even worse then having a single table with those redundancy.